# Emacs + R: too long buffer name */usr/local/bin/R* for R buffers

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I work with Emacs 24 (Emacs-pretest-24.0.91-universal-10.6.7 from http://emacsformacosx.com/builds) on Mac OS X 10.7.3 with R 2.15. When I open a new R buffer, the buffer name is `*/usr/local/bin/R*`. For all other buffers I receive a reasonable file name, but for R buffers, the filename always contains this path. This is quite annoying if you have multiple R buffers open and you display a buffer menu (for example). Then you see a lot of buffers displayed as `*/usr/local/...` and you can't see which of the buffers corresponds to which R process.

Is this a problem of the Mac or just my setup?

The only thing I can image as a reason for this is the following. To call R from the console (as from within Emacs), I defined a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin` pointing to the correct path where R is installed. This link I called "R".

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R R
```

I could imagine that the emacs buffer name is determined from the link `/usr/lcoal/bin/R` but I don't know how to fix this since without the link I can't start R. On Ubuntu, I simply see the buffer name R (or R[2],... etc.), it would be great to have the same on Mac OS.

**Update**

```
inferior-R-program-name is a variable defined in `ess-custom.el'.
Its value is "/usr/local/bin/R"
Original value was "R"

ess-dialect is a variable defined in `ess-custom.el'.
Its value is "R"
Local in buffer */usr/local/bin/R*; global value is "R"
Automatically becomes buffer-local when set in any fashion.

ess-use-inferior-program-name-in-buffer-name is a variable defined in `ess-custom.el'.
Its value is t
Original value was nil
```

Comment: What is the value of `inferior-R-program-name`, `ess-dialect` and `ess-use-inferior-program-name-in-buffer-name`? (You can find out with `C-h v` and typing the name of the variable)

Comment: Thanks for helping, Ernest. I added the information above. I guess `inferior-R-program-name` looks suspicious.

Comment: I think you have two options: either set `inferior-R-program-name` to `"R"` (and make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`), or set `ess-use-inferior-program-name-in-buffer-name` to `nil`.

Comment: Many thanks, Ernest, setting `(setq-default inferior-R-program-name "R")` in `.emacs` perfectly solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options: either set `inferior-R-program-name` to `"R"` (and make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`), or set `ess-use-inferior-program-name-in-buffer-name` to `nil` which will set the buffer name to the value of `ess-dialect`.